# How to reverse a series in pandas by Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to reverse a series for correct plotting.

So I wrote the code below:

```py
dataFrame["close"] = dataFrame["close"][::-1]
```

But it doesn't differ. Why?

Comment: As a data integrity mechanism `pandas` ensures that indexes align. Since 'close' has not been reindexed it will end up in the original order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the specific column. You should reverse the entire dataframe like this:

```
dataFrame.reindex(index=dataFrame.index[::-1])
```

or

```
dataFrame.iloc[::-1]
```